# Can i get features of the clusters using hierarchical clustering - numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical

I am trying to do hierarchical clustering on an m*n array.

1. Input array : 500 * 1000 (1000 features, 500 observations)
2. Calculate distance matrix using a self-defined pdist function
3. Feed this distance matrix to linkage function : 
       clusters = sch.linkage(distanceMatrix,'single')
4. Form flat clusters : 
       fc = sch.fcluster(clusters,cutoff,'distance')

This gives me some clusters (around 80, using a cutoff value of 6.0).
Now, is there anyway, that i can get the 1000 features corresponding to each cluster as well? ( like we get the features of the centroids using K-means clustering).

Answer (score 3):

Clusters in hierarchical clustering (or pretty much anything except k-means and Gaussian Mixture EM that are restricted to "spherical" - actually: convex - clusters) do **not necessarily have sensible means**.

Because they allow for non-spherical clusters. That actually is a feature...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Connectivity_based_clustering_.28hierarchical_clustering.29

Have a look at the right image titled "Linkage clustering examples". What good is a cluster in this "banana" example? **The centroid might not even be in the cluster!**

Note that you can still compute the centroid *yourself*, if you need it. As the clustering algorithm does not need the centroid, it will not be computing it for you automatically, obviously.